# Open a folder in explorer using Java

Tags: java

From Java code, how do I open a specific folder (e.g. C:\Folder) in the platform's file explorer (e.g. Windows Explorer)?  The examples are for Windows but I need a cross platform solution.

Comment: I don't get why this is closed as not a real question. It seems very clear and useful to me. I do wish we could close some of the comments instead.

Answer (score 92):

Quite simply:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\folder"));
```

Note: `java.awt.Desktop` was introduced in JDK 6.

Comment: Surround with 'try/catch' or add 'throws' clause for IOException

Comment: This answer, as well as the other answers, do not work on my computer (Debian/KDE). Perhaps someone can come with solution that works on most platforms? (on my computer it should open the Dolphin file manager)

Comment: This method hangs the JVM in ubuntu.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can do it with JDK 6 with the below code:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenFolder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        File dirToOpen = null;
        try {
            dirToOpen = new File("c:\\folder");
            desktop.open(dirToOpen);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
```

is not supported in JDK 5

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer C:\bin");
```

Comment: Worth noting that this would only work in Windows