# Open a File in default File explorer and highlight it using JavaFX or plain Java

Tags: java, javafx, io, explorer

I wish to do what the title says.

---

**Part Solution:**

For example in `Windows` you can use the code below to open a file in the default explorer and highlight it.

(`although it needs modification for files containing spaces`):

```java
/**
 * Opens the file with the System default file explorer.
 *
 * @param path the path
 */
public static void openFileLocation(String path) {
    if (InfoTool.osName.toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select," + path);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Main.logger.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Useful Links:**

Links which are similar but `no way dublicates` or not answered:

[How to use java code to open Windows file explorer and highlight the specified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357969/how-to-use-java-code-to-open-windows-file-explorer-and-highlight-the-specified-f#7369564)

[Open a folder in explorer using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875295/open-a-folder-in-explorer-using-java)

[How can I open the default system browser from a java fx application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604341/how-can-i-open-the-default-system-browser-from-a-java-fx-application#16615384)

---

**More explanation:**

- Is there a way to do it using JavaFX ?

  ```
    If not at least i need a link or some way to make the app system  
     independence.I mean i don't know the default explorer for every OS     
     that the application is going to work , i need a link or help doing that.
  ```
- Do i need to write a ton of code to do this?
- Is out there any library for doing that?
- Do Java9 support that?

---

**Finally:**

It is very strange that for so common things i can't find answers and libraries .

---

Example of highlighted or selected in Windows 10:

[image]

Comment: I am ready to give bounty for the brave who will find the answer ;)

Comment: `I mean i don't know the default explorer for every OS that the application is going to work ` - That is what the `Desktop` API is for. You already linked to and answer with that solution. So what is wrong with that class?

Comment: @camickr Hello camickr . First it is using `Swing Library` , Second it just opens the file in the default explorer and no way i can highlight it . It only answers partially the question and is using different Framework which is causing problems and it is soon to be obsolete.

Comment: What is the difference between plain Java and Swing? The Swig API is part of the base JDK. What do you mean highlight?

Comment: `Example of highlighted or selected in Windows 10:` - yes well Java doesn't have access to the individual API of a application that runs in a Windows environment. I'm sure for this you need a lower level language.

Comment: @camickr I added an image . Yes it is part of the JDK(althought it is very awesome it will soon not be , maybe it is 5 years or sooner) . It doesn't fit well along with `JavaFX` . I need something which will stay .

Comment: The first linked answer you posted has two options of achieving what you are looking for. Beyond that, you can create a javafx window which list all the files of a folder and highlights the appropriate file. This second approach will require a lot of coding.

Comment: I personally think that you are confused about JavaFx. It only handles GUI creation. You have to use other libraries to add functionality. JavaFx is not a utility API.   JavaFX was intended to replace Swing as the standard GUI library for Java SE

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson The first link has the answer only for `Windows` and it actually not working well in some cases . A more complete approach with links for other operating system will be excellent .

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson As JavaFX continues to envolve i think it may present a functionality or library like this , by calling the native System through JNI. Actually it will be amazing if such a feature is presented . Any solution including third party libraries is highly accepted . You can see that Swing has Desktop API.

Comment: It's really a pity that this isn't answered. I have exactly the same need.

Comment: @ice1000 For windows you can use the code added on question, for Linux and Mac, well '' wait till i find the answer son :) ''

Comment: Sign. Difference machine has difference file explorer, and I have no idea how to adapt more OSs.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 9 it's possible with the new method browseFileDirectory, so your method would state:

```java
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
...

/**
 * Opens the file with the System default file explorer.
 *
 * @param path the path
 */
public static void openFileLocation(String path) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browseFileDirectory(new File(path));
}
```

For more information, refer to the javadoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browseFileDirectory(java.io.File)

Comment: That's awesome, just one question, it also selects the file in the explorer?

Comment: The oracle documentation says yes. I've tested on windows7 and works. In my manjaro linux i3 community edition throws an exception since the platform doesn't support the operation, but I think that on KDE or Gnome should work fine.

Comment: Perfect i will do tests :)

Comment: Just tested on Windows 10 .... `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The BROWSE_FILE_DIR action is not supported on the current platform!` i am like whatttttt ...using Java 9.0.4

Comment: See [JDK-8233994](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8233994). Windows 10 is intentional not supported. No idea why. Perhaps it was simply forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

Windows

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer /select, <file path>")
```

Linux

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xdg-open <file path>");
```

MacOS

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -R <file path>");
```

Comment: Note that `explorer "/select,<file path>"` doesn't work for file paths that happen to contain a `,` character.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a partial answer showing you how to open the system folder you desire, but not how to highlight a specific file since I do not believe it is possible to highlight a file in a system folder, because that is probably a system OS function that cannot be accessed by Java.

This is written in Javafx code

In your Main class make a variable for Hostservices. Note that "yourFileLocation" is the address of the folder to the file, and SettsBtn is a button that exists somewhere which the user clicks to execute the code:

```java
public class Main extends Application{

    static HostServices Host; //<-- sort of a global variable

    //some code here to make your GUI

    public Main() {
        //more code here to initialize things
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //some code here to set the stage

        //This code here opens the file explorer
        SettsBtn.setOnMouseClicked(e-> {
            Path partPath = Paths.get("yourFileLocation");
            Host = getHostServices();
            Host.showDocument(partPath.toUri().toString());
        });
    }
}
```

Note that you could directly open the file by making a string to the file location and the file name with its extension, such as:

```java
Path partPath = Paths.get("yourFileLocation"+"\\"+"yourFileName.ext");
```

Comment: Shows in Chrome :D

Answer (score 1):

As of `Java 17` the `Desktop::browseFileDirectory` method is still not supported on `Windows 10` or later.

The historic reason is that Apple originally implemented these native Desktop integration features for `Mac OS X` in the `com.apple.eawt` package back when Apple itself was still maintaining the JDK for `Mac OS X`. All of that was ported into `java.awt.Desktop` for `Java 9` as per [JEP 272: Platform-Specific Desktop Features](https://openjdk.org/jeps/272) and so I guess some of these features are still only implemented for `Mac OS X` to this day.

Fortunately, `Windows 10` does have a [SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems) function that we can call via `JNA` like so:

```java
public interface Shell32 extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32 {
    Shell32 INSTANCE = Native.load("shell32", Shell32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    HRESULT SHParseDisplayName(WString pszName, Pointer pbc, PointerByReference ppidl, WinDef.ULONG sfgaoIn, Pointer psfgaoOut);
    HRESULT SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(Pointer pidlFolder, WinDef.UINT cidl, Pointer apidl, WinDef.DWORD dwFlags);
}
```

```java
public class Shell32Util extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32Util {

    public static Pointer SHParseDisplayName(File file) {
        try {
            PointerByReference ppidl = new PointerByReference();

            // canonicalize file path for Win32 API
            HRESULT hres = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHParseDisplayName(new WString(file.getCanonicalPath()), null, ppidl, new WinDef.ULONG(0), null);
            if (W32Errors.FAILED(hres)) {
                throw new Win32Exception(hres);
            }

            return ppidl.getValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InvalidPathException(file.getPath(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(File file) {
        Pointer pidlFolder = SHParseDisplayName(file);

        try {
            HRESULT hres = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlFolder, new WinDef.UINT(0), null, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
            if (W32Errors.FAILED(hres)) {
                throw new Win32Exception(hres);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InvalidPathException(file.getPath(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```